# Calculation Unit Piece in GridControl error

Tags: c#

I have a gridcontrol and in there `unitPrice`, `TotalPrice` and `Quantity` column. When i use this code to calculate `unitPrice` it calculates the first row and another rows in `UnitPrice = 0` Please help?

```
private void Chillers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ornekTblTableAdapter.Fill(this.chillersDataSet.OrnekTbl);

    InitMDBData();

    var row = gridView1.GetFocusedDataRow();

    var totalprice = Convert.ToDecimal(row["TotalPrice"]);
    var quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Quantity"]);
    row["UnitPrice"] = totalprice / quantity;
}
```

Comment: What is that gridcontrol? `DataGridView`, `DataGrid` Web or Win?

Comment: by the way you calaculate for only focused row, so others will be obviously untouched.

Comment: devexpress gridview, win

Comment: @user3198433: Please don't forget to mark the question as answered if it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

You need a simple foreach loop

```
foreach(var row in gridView1.Rows)
{
    var totalprice = Convert.ToDecimal(row["TotalPrice"]);
    var quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Quantity"]);
    row["UnitPrice"] = totalprice / quantity;
}
```

Update: for your special dataGridView try this:

```
for(int i=0; i< gridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    var totalprice = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "TotalPrice"));
    var quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(gridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "Quantity"));
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i,"UnitPrice",(totalprice / quantity));
}
```

Comment: does not contain a definition for "Rows"

Comment: Is this winforms ? and default dataGridView ?

Comment: it is devexpress form

Comment: It should be one of those properties :-) http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridViewClassPropTopic

Comment: i know but really i cant do it(((

Comment: i respect to you!!! thanks for your kind interest, it works!!! :))  tesekkur ederim :)

Answer (score 0):

You are only changing one row, gridView1.GetFocusedDataRow().

You need to either add the computed value to the original data source, or put a data binding expression in your gridview markup, i.e.

```
<asp:templatecolumn><%# Eval(((decimal)Container.DataItem["TotalPrice"]) / ((decimal)Container.DataItem["TotalPrice"]) %></asp:templatecolumn>
```